# Feature fails to start using Karaf 4.2.16 due to unresolved dependencies

Tags: java, maven, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

I try to start a feature using Karaf console:

`karaf@karaf()> feature:install my_feature`

and get the following error:

```
Error executing command: 
Unable to resolve root: 
    missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; 
    osgi.identity=my_feature; 
    type=karaf.feature; 
    version="[4.0.0.SNAPSHOT,4.0.0.SNAPSHOT]"; 
    filter:="(&(osgi.identity=my_feature)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=4.0.0.SNAPSHOT)(version<=4.0.0.SNAPSHOT))" 
    [
        caused by: Unable to resolve my_feature/4.0.0.SNAPSHOT: 
        missing requirement [my_feature/4.0.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; 
        osgi.identity=appliance-branding; 
        type=osgi.bundle; 
        version="[4.0.0.SNAPSHOT,4.0.0.SNAPSHOT]"; 
        resolution:=mandatory 
        [
            caused by: Unable to resolve appliance-branding/4.0.0.SNAPSHOT: 
            missing requirement [appliance-branding/4.0.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.wiring.package; 
            filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.blueprint)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))"
        ]
    ]
```

However, I manually added the org.osgi.service.blueprint bundle and having it active:

```
karaf@karaf()> list
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
ID │ State  │ Lvl │ Version            │ Name
───┼────────┼─────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────
27 │ Active │ 100 │ 4.2.16             │ Apache Karaf :: OSGi Services :: Event
51 │ Active │  80 │ 1.0.2.201505202024 │ org.osgi:org.osgi.service.blueprint
```

The question is why Karaf ignores the org.osgi.service.blueprint bundle and can't install my feature and what I can do to install it?

UPD: I used Karaf 2.2.x and I didn't have any issues with it, now I'm trying to upgrade from 2.2.x to 4.2.16. I built my application using Java 6 for Karaf 2.2.x and now I'm using Java 8 along with Karaf 4.2.16. The source code is absolutely the same, nothing was changed except Java version I'm using to build.

Comment: Please install `aries-blueprint` feature - that's how Karaf itself uses blueprint.